# Get resolution from camera using onvif

Tags: php, soap, onvif

I'm trying to get current video resolution from my onvif supported camera using **[GetVideoOutputs](https://www.onvif.org/onvif/ver10/deviceio.wsdl#op.GetVideoOutputs)**. When I run this implementation in a **php** script I'm getting the following error:-

```
Array
(
[Envelope] => Array
    (
        [Header] => Array
            (
            )

        [Body] => Array
            (
                [Fault] => Array
                    (
                        [@attributes] => Array
                            (
                                [encodingStyle] => http://www.w3.org/2003/05/soap-encoding
                            )

                        [Code] => Array
                            (
                                [Value] => SOAP-ENV:Receiver
                                [Subcode] => Array
                                    (
                                        [Value] => ter:Action
                                    )

                            )

                        [Reason] => Array
                            (
                                [Text] => Action failed
                            )

                        [Detail] => Array
                            (
                                [Text] => The requested SOAP action failed
                            )

                    )

            )

    )

)
```

Comment: All you show to us is a generic non-descriptive error message in an array dump. What are we supposed to do about this? You need to find out why "The requested SOAP action failed"

Answer (score 1):

Using GetVideoOutputs from the Device I/O service to get the video resolutions available for streaming is wrong.

As you can see in [§5.1.1 of the Device I/O specs](https://www.onvif.org/specs/srv/io/ONVIF-DeviceIo-Service-Spec-v1706.pdf),

> This command lists all available video  outputs  of  a  device.  A 
>   device  that  has  one  or  more physical   video   outputs shall
>   support listing of available   video   outputs   through   the 
>   GetVideoOutputs command.

To get the video resolution you must use:

- the [Media Service](https://www.onvif.org/specs/srv/media/ONVIF-Media-Service-Spec-v1706.pdf) if your camera is Profile S compliant, see §5.5
- the [Media Service 2](https://www.onvif.org/specs/srv/media/ONVIF-Media2-Service-Spec-v1706.pdf) if your camera is Profile T compliant, see §5.2.3 . By now, this profile is not released yet, thus it is very unlikely that this is your case.